# Creating an expression from the string of a property name?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, iqueryable, dynamic-queries

I am trying to create a query based on some JSON, I currently have the JSON parsed into a set of rules, each rule contains the name of the field, the type of comparison (=, > etc) and the value to compare.

The issue I am having is getting it from that rule, to an IQueryable object, I am guessing I need to use reflection and somehow build the expression tree, but I'm not sure on the right approach...

Assuming I have:

```
public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public int OrderID{ get; set; }
}
```

and I have the rule which is:

```
public class Rule
    {
        public string field { get; set; }
        public Operations op { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }
```

Running it I get:

```
field = "OrderID"
op = "eq"
data = "123"
```

I have the method to parse it with the signature:

```
public IQueryable<T> FilterObjectSet<T>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery) where T : class
```

As part of this method I want to do:

```
inputQuery = inputQuery.Where(o => propertyInfo.Name == rule1.data);
```

This doesn't work because it basically just generates the sql "OrderID" = "123" which is obviously wrong, I need it to take the column name from inputQuery that has the same name as propertyInfo.Name and build the query that way...

Hope that made sense? Any suggestions?

Edit: I guess what I am asking is to convert a string (Because I can build one pretty simply from the rule) to an expression, maybe using Dynamic LINQ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end I used a Dynamic Linq library I found on Guthrie's Blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Using this I was able to properly parse out and use the parameters I had built into the rules

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterObjectSet<T>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, 
                                               Rule rule) where T : class
{
    var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(par, rule.field);
    var propType = prop.Member.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field ? 
                               ((FieldInfo)prop.Member).FieldType : 
                               ((PropertyInfo)prop.Member).PropertyType);

    // I convert the data that is a string to the "correct" type here
    object data2 = Convert.ChangeType(rule.data, 
                                      propType, 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var eq = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(data2));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eq, par);

    return inputQuery.Where(lambda);
}
```

If you need some explanation, you can ask. Note that this won't work on types that have special implicit conversions (like a `MyString` type that has an implicit conversion from `string`). This because `Convert.ChangeType` uses only the `IConvertible` interface.

Null handling for `data` is perhaps something else that should be handled.

Be aware that I'm not sure the `Expression.PropertyOrField` is handled by the various `IQueryable<T>` engines (LINQ-to-SQL and EF). I have only tested it with the `AsQueryable()` engine. If they don't "accept" it, you must split it in a  `Expression.Property` or `Expression.Field` depending on what `rule.field` is.

A nearly equivalent version that doesn't use `Expression.PropertyOrField`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterObjectSet<T>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, 
                                               Rule rule) where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var par = Expression.Parameter(type);

    Type fieldPropertyType;
    Expression fieldPropertyExpression;

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(rule.field);

    if (fieldInfo == null)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(rule.field);

        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        fieldPropertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        fieldPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(par, propertyInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        fieldPropertyType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
        fieldPropertyExpression = Expression.Field(par, fieldInfo);
    }

    object data2 = Convert.ChangeType(rule.data, fieldPropertyType);
    var eq = Expression.Equal(fieldPropertyExpression, 
                              Expression.Constant(data2));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eq, par);
    return inputQuery.Where(lambda);
}
```

Comment: This is good but there are some limitations I would need to overcome, namely nullable type conversions and handling of the operator, thanks though, I will see if I can adapt to my purpose